# How to translate SQL statement with multiple join conditions based on subquery to LINQ

Tags: c#, sql, linq, linq-to-sql, join

This might be one of those situations where plain SQL commands are better than LINQ. Here's a simplified version of the SQL statement I'm trying to translate:

```
SELECT * FROM IDTable AS idt 
INNER JOIN NameTable AS nt ON nt.IDTableID=idt.Id 
         AND nt.Id= (SELECT TOP(1) Id 
                     FROM NameTable AS nt2 
                     WHERE nt2.IDTableID=11 ORDER BY nt2.DateInserted DESC)
```

I have the LINQ query to pull records when just joining on IDs and I've seen how to join on multiple columns, but I have no idea how to plug the subquery into the mix.
If this isnt entirely clear, please let me know and I'll edit to elaborate.

Comment: Thanks for making the query more readable!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like this?

```
var results = from id in db.IDTable
              join n in db.NameTable on id.Id equals n.IDTableID
              where n.Id = (
                  from n2 in db.NameTable
                  where n2.IDTableID = 11
                  orderby n2.DateInserted desc
                  ).First()
              select new { id, n };
```